# Error installing Syft 0.2.5 in Colab: subprocess exited with error

Tags: python, scipy, google-colaboratory, pysyft

I am trying to install Syft version 0.2.5 on Google Colab using the command !pip install syft==0.2.5. However, I am running into an error while installing the scipy dependency. The error message indicates that the subprocess to install the build dependencies did not run successfully, with exit code 1.
I am encountering following error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (23.0.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-23.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 21.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 23.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-23.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-23.0.1
Successfully installed pip-23.1.2
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting syft==0.2.5
  Using cached syft-0.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (369 kB)
Collecting flask-socketio~=4.2.1 (from syft==0.2.5)
  Using cached Flask_SocketIO-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Flask~=1.1.1 (from syft==0.2.5)
  Using cached Flask-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting lz4~=3.0.2 (from syft==0.2.5)
  Using cached lz4-3.0.2.tar.gz (152 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack~=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from syft==0.2.5) (1.0.5)
Collecting numpy~=1.18.1 (from syft==0.2.5)
  Using cached numpy-1.18.5.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting phe~=1.4.0 (from syft==0.2.5)
  Using cached phe-1.4.0.tar.gz (35 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting Pillow~=6.2.2 (from syft==0.2.5)
  Using cached Pillow-6.2.2.tar.gz (37.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting requests~=2.22.0 (from syft==0.2.5)
  Downloading requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 58.0/58.0 kB 2.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting scipy~=1.4.1 (from syft==0.2.5)
  Using cached scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz (24.6 MB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue.